# Accessing a file in another users home directory using setfacl

Tags: linux, permissions, acl, setfacl

I was trying to access a file on another users home directory using acl. I have tried to do it the following way.

User k9 made a file test.file and ran

```
setfacl -m u:sai:rwx test.file.
```

Following is the getfacl output.

```
k9@xxxx:~$ getfacl test.file
# file: test.file
# owner: k9
# group: k9
user::rw-
user:sai:rwx
group::rw-
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

And from user sai I tried accessing this file

```
sai@xxxx:~$ ls /home/k9/
ls: cannot open directory '/home/k9/': Permission denied
sai@xxxx:~$ ls /home/k9/test.file
ls: cannot access '/home/k9/test.file': Permission denied
```

Can we use setfacl to access test.file without having complete access to /home/k9/ ? If so what am I doing wrong and if not how can that be done?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What does `getfacl /home/k9/` reveal when run as user `k9`?

Comment: sai@xxxx:~$ getfacl /home/k9/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/k9/
# owner: k9
# group: k9
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
@AdminBee

Comment: The problem is: If you don't have "execute" rights on a directory, you cannot access any files within it, simply because you can't "enter" it.

Comment: @AdminBee is there a way to have some other way to do this then? Access just a specific file in another directory? Also what exactly does giving execute rights to the directory do?

Answer (score 0):

you do not have permissions on directories, apply ACL on them as well

Comment: If I do that will I not have access to all files inside the directories? I only want permissions to the single file test.file @csx4